# Mysql report missing data

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, report

I have the following tables:

Orders:

```
|order_id|customer_id|      order_date      |item_id|quantity|
|--------|-----------|----------------------|-------|--------|
|   1    |  1        |  2020-06-01 00:00:00 |   1   |      10|
|   2    |  1        |  2020-06-08 00:00:00 |   2   |      10|
|   3    |  2        |  2020-06-02 00:00:00 |   1   |      5 |
|   4    |  3        |  2020-06-03 00:00:00 |   3   |      5 |
|   5    |  4        |  2020-06-04 00:00:00 |   4   |      1 |
|   6    |  4        |  2020-06-05 00:00:00 |   5   |      5 |
|   7    |  5        |  2020-06-05 00:00:00 |   1   |      10|
|   8    |  5        |  2020-06-14 00:00:00 |   4   |      5 |
|   9    |  5        |  2020-06-21 00:00:00 |   3   |      5 |
|   5    |  4        |  2020-06-08 00:00:00 |   4   |      1 |
```

Items:

```
|item_id|item_name          |item_category|
|-------|---------  --------|-------------|
|   1   |LC Alg. Book       |Book         |
|   2   |LC DB. Book        |Book         |
|   3   |LC SmarthPhone     |Phone        |
|   4   |LC Phone 2020      |Phone        |
|   5   |LC SmartGlass      |Glasses      |
|   6   |LC T-Shirt XL      |T-Shirt      |
```

Im creating a query that should return a report on how many units in each item_category have been ordered on each day of the week. The report should look like:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Category   | Monday    | Tuesday   | Wednesday | Thursday  | Friday    | Saturday  | Sunday    |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Book       | 20        | 5         | 0         | 0         | 10        | 0         | 0         |
| Glasses    | 0         | 0         | 0         | 0         | 5         | 0         | 0         |
| Phone      | 0         | 0         | 5         | 1         | 0         | 0         | 10        |
| T-Shirt    | 0         | 0         | 0         | 0         | 0         | 0         | 0         |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Following is my query, which is accurate for all but one case - 'Phone' on Thursday should be qty = 1 but my query returns 0. This quantity is returned accurately in cte2, but I loose it in cte3. Can't figure out why. What's wrong with my query?

```
with cte1 as 
    (select * from
        (select "Monday" as day_name union 
        select "Tuesday" union
        select "Wednesday" union
        select "Thursday " union
        select "Friday" union
        select "Saturday " union
        select "Sunday" ) t1
     cross join
        (select distinct item_category from items) t2),
cte2 as 
    (select i.item_category, 
        dayname(order_date) as day_name,
        sum(quantity) as tt_qty
    from orders o
    inner join items i 
    on i.item_id  = o.item_id 
    group by i.item_category, dayname(order_date)),
cte3 as
    (select cte1.day_name,
        cte1.item_category,
        coalesce(cte2.tt_qty, 0) as tt_qty
    from cte1
    left join cte2
    on cte2.day_name = cte1.day_name
    and cte2.item_category = cte1.item_category)
select item_category as category, 
    coalesce (max(case when cte3.day_name ='Monday' then cte3.tt_qty 
        end),0) as Monday,
    coalesce (max(case when cte3.day_name ='Tuesday' then cte3.tt_qty 
        end),0) as Tuesday,
    coalesce (max(case when cte3.day_name ='Wednesday' then cte3.tt_qty 
        end),0) as Wednesday,
    coalesce (max(case when cte3.day_name ='Thursday' then cte3.tt_qty
        end),0) as Thursday,
    coalesce (max(case when cte3.day_name ='Friday' then cte3.tt_qty 
        end),0) as Friday,
    coalesce (max(case when cte3.day_name ='Saturday' then cte3.tt_qty 
        end),0) as Saturday,
    coalesce (max(case when cte3.day_name ='Sunday' then cte3.tt_qty 
        end),0) as Sunday       
from cte3
group by item_category
order by 1
```

DBfiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=sD7fqL9voK

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please per the links given, put everything needed to ask your post in your post, not just at a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space after the "y" in Thursday and Saturday of `cte1`, hence the join isn't working as expected and the coalesce is returning zero for all Thursdays/Saturdays. The following replacement of `cte1` will make the query work as expected.

```
with cte1 as 
    (select * from
        (select 1 as wd, "Monday" as day_name union all
        select 2, "Tuesday" union all
        select 3, "Wednesday" union all
        select 4, "Thursday" union all ## you had a space after "Thursday "
        select 5, "Friday" union all
        select 6, "Saturday" union all ## you had a space after "Saturday "
        select 7, "Sunday" ) t1
     cross join
        (select distinct item_category from items) t2),
```

see: *dbfiddle.uk [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a0502c1b3cd021385bae20e2630f924)*

I introduced an integer for the weekdays as it made ordering easier, also used `union all` instead of just `union`

Answer (score 0):

With mySQL 8.0 my solution in just 3 SELECTs and 1 JOIN:

(but there is 0 as wrong value on monday for the phone item because of Phone/4  2020-06-08 Monday item in orders table)

```
CREATE TABLE orders_tab
(order_id INT, customer_id INT, order_date DATE, item_id INT, qty INT);
INSERT INTO orders_tab VALUES
(1, 1, '2020-06-01', 1, 10),
(2, 1, '2020-06-08', 2, 10),
(3, 2, '2020-06-02', 1, 5),
(4, 3, '2020-06-03', 3, 5),
(5, 4, '2020-06-04', 4, 1),
(6, 4, '2020-06-05', 5, 5),
(7, 5, '2020-06-05', 1, 10),
(8, 5, '2020-06-14', 4, 5),
(9, 5, '2020-06-21', 3, 5),
(5, 4, '2020-06-08', 4, 1);
CREATE TABLE items_tab
(item_id INT, item_name VARCHAR(22), item_cat VARCHAR(9));
INSERT INTO items_tab VALUES
(1, 'LC Alg. Book', 'Book'),
(2, 'LC DB. Book', 'Book'),
(3, 'LC SmarthPhone', 'Phone'),
(4, 'LC Phone 2020', 'Phone'),
(5, 'LC SmartGlass', 'Glasses'),
(6, 'LC T-Shirt XL', 'T-Shirt');
/*___________________________________*/
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT item_cat, WEEKDAY(order_date) AS week_day, OT.item_id, SUM(qty) AS items_qty_by_day
    FROM orders_tab OT
    RIGHT JOIN items_tab IT ON (OT.item_id=IT.item_id)
    GROUP BY week_day, OT.item_id
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT week_day, item_cat, SUM(items_qty_by_day) AS items_qty_by_day 
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY week_day, item_cat
)
SELECT item_cat, 
    SUM(IF(week_day=0, items_qty_by_day, 0)) AS monday,
    SUM(IF(week_day=1, items_qty_by_day, 0)) AS tuesday,
    SUM(IF(week_day=2, items_qty_by_day, 0)) AS wednesday,
    SUM(IF(week_day=3, items_qty_by_day, 0)) AS thursday,
    SUM(IF(week_day=4, items_qty_by_day, 0)) AS friday,
    SUM(IF(week_day=5, items_qty_by_day, 0)) AS saturday,
    SUM(IF(week_day=6, items_qty_by_day, 0)) AS sunday
FROM cte2
GROUP BY item_cat
```